# Center and layer multiple DIVs with flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I would like to layer multiple DIVs on top of one another while using flexbox to vertically and horizontally center them both.

In the example below, I would like both `.whitebox` and `.bluebox` to be vertically and horizontally centered inside of the container, overlapping one another. Currently `.whitebox` is positioned with absolute position. Is this possible?

```css
.container {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.bluebox {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: #0073FF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.whitebox {
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bluebox"></div>
  <div class="whitebox"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the offsets like below, it will get the small box centered with the existing rules you set on everything else.

```
.whitebox {
  ...
  /* top: 0; */
  /* left: 0; */
}
```

**Edit:** The above works in Chrome, but doesn't seem to be working in Firefox.

In fact, I would simplify the entire code as follows. It should work everywhere where flexbox is supported.

```css
.bluebox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: #0073FF;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.whitebox {
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bluebox">
  <div class="whitebox"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to position the `top` and `left`. Just applying absolute positioning is enough because that "pops" the elements into their own layers, so they can be placed at will without affecting other elements in that layer. Once you do that, the `align-items` and `justify-content` will do their jobs.

```css
.container {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.bluebox {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: #0073FF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;

}

.whitebox {
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;

}

.border {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bluebox"></div>
  <div class="whitebox"></div>
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Roey Uh, yes, that's right modern stuff like Flexbox doesn't work in IE. But since the OP asked why his Flexbox code didn't work, this is the answer. Not to mention that, unless you have a specific business requirement for it, writing code to be compatible with IE isn't a "thing" anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use the usual method for centering: The container gets `position: relative` and defined width and height, the elements to-be-centered inside the container get this CSS:

```
.centered-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Plus `z-index` values for the order in which they are above each other, and possibly `opacity` so they all can be seen simultaneously...

So in your example, that would be

```css
.container {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

.bluebox {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: #0073FF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.whitebox {
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bluebox"></div>
  <div class="whitebox"></div>
</div>
```

The flexbox properties are superfluous when you do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Set your divs up like this:

```
 <div class="parent">
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="whitebox"></div>
     <div class="bluebox"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then apply this css:

```
 .parent{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

 .wrapper{
    position:relative
 }
 .whitebox, .bluebox{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin-left` and `margin-top` because you know the height and width of your element.

**Explanation:**

- Move your element from top `50%` and from left `50%`.
- Move your element `4px` from right and `4px` from bottom.

```css
.container {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.bluebox {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: #0073FF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.whitebox {
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px
}

.border {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bluebox"></div>
  <div class="whitebox"></div>
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```